# Load image from solution in WebView Xamarin Forms

Tags: webview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have inside ScrollView images and i want selected image opened in some new page and have pinch and zoom , i try webview control but i cant load image from my solution path .

```
void loadhtml()
   {
     var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource {
     Html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<body>\n<img src=\"myproject.Images.test.jpg\">\n</body>\n</html>"
    };
    MyWebView.Source = htmlSource;
   }
```

Can i load image from path where is inside my app in WebView ? Another method for pinch and zoom ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact load content that is bundled into you app with the Xamarin.Forms WebView. See this link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/

I hope that helps!